# Google APIClient Class not found using Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, google-api-php-client

I´m using composer to install the the google api client [Packagist Google API Client](https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient).

After I installed it using composer require google/apiclient it installed like normal.
After that I tried to use it in the example below

```
<?php
use Google\Service\ShoppingContent;
use Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials;

/**
 *
 */
class GoogleShoppingContentAPI
{
  private $service;

  public function __construct($credentialsPath) {
    // Create the credentials object
    $credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials(
        ShoppingContent::CONTENT,
        $credentialsPath
    );
    // Create the Shopping Content Service with the credentials
    $this->service = new ShoppingContent(['credentials' => $credentials]);
  }

  public function getProducts($merchantID)
  {
    try {
      // Fetch a list of products
      $products = $this->service->products->listProducts($merchantID);
      // Return the product data as an array
      return $products->getResources();
    } catch (Google\Service\Exception $e) {
      throw new Exception("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

However when running the code it prints out this error:

```
Class Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials" not found in /Users/Shared/www/inc/google.inc.php on line 15
```

It is in our autoload and our autoload is required before running the code aboved.
The Google namespace isnt occupied by another package aswell.

I already looked through our project and did not found any duplicate namespaces related to google.
Also reinstalling aswell composer update did not changed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I´m a bit embarrassed to admit but I ran the composer require command in the wrong folder.
So that's why it got installed but it wasn't able to be autoloaded.
Shame on me.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at the github source of that library suggests that the class you're looking for isn't there any more:
https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-php-client/main/

You probably need a more up-to-date guide to follow.
If you look at the github readme.md: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client you'll see some examples of how to use the API now. Good luck!